# Does Brotli compress better with a larger window?

Tags: compression, brotli

What is the window size in Brotli?

Is it true that setting a larger window size improves the compression ratio?

Comment: What is this "conversion rate"?

Comment: @MarkAdler I wanted to say compression rate.

Comment: Hmm. I will assume you mean compression _ratio_, which is the factor by which the data is reduced in size. The compression _rate_ would be how fast the data is compressed, in MB/sec. Do you mean the ratio?

Comment: @MarkAdler Yes, compression ratio

Answer (score 0):

From RFC 7932:

> The possible sliding window sizes range from 1 KiB - 16 B to 16 MiB -
> 16 B.

In general, yes, a larger window size will improve the compression ratio, but only if the data is likely to have repeating strings that are that far away from each other. You can google for compression benchmarks that include varying the window size.